# how to get the list of elements matching attribute from HTMLDivElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is an example source.

```
<div ref={this.mainRef}>
   <div>
      <ul>
         <li role="option" id="1">A</li>
         <li role="option" id="2">B</li>
         <li role="option" id="3">C</li>
         <li role="option" id="4">A</li>
         <li role="option" id="5">B</li>
         <li role="option" id="6">C</li>
      
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

With `this.mainRef`, how do I get the list of elements matching attribute of 'role=option'?

Something like..

```
const selectableOptions = this.mainRef.children.search(role=option)
```

- I don't want to go through the DOMs tree because the structure might get changed.
- I would like to "search" instead.

THANKS!

Comment: What's wrong with `querySelectorAll` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) ?

Comment: Can we do it with react way..?

Comment: In "react way" you should not really do something like this. What's the exact problem?

Comment: a react way would be not to try manipulate the dom manually, try to look for a way to manipulate only state and data those element are using, we'll more details about you want to do to provide a react-ish way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below.

```js
const divRef = useRef(null)
```

```html
<div ref={divRef}>
   <div>
      <ul>
         <li role="option" id="1">A</li>
         <li role="option" id="2">B</li>
         <li role="option" id="3">C</li>
         <li role="option" id="4">A</li>
         <li role="option" id="5">B</li>
         <li role="option" id="6">C</li>
      
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
const matches = divRef.current.querySelectorAll("li[role='option']");
```